# read/write file in controlled network shared folder

Tags: c++, vb.net

I have a shared folder with full access to certain users only. Does it possible to read/write those files by passing user detail (1 of the full access accounts rather than everyone) by using VB.NET or C++ fopen command?

Comment: As far as I know, processes have a user id. So irrespective of your code, the user that runs the application makes the difference rather than your code.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? It is a reasonable question

Comment: actually i plan to assign 1 windows user id who has full access to the folder in my source code to perform read/write function, so i do not need to share the folder to "everyone". Wondering how to do as the fopen command just passing the network path+filename only.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the user who is executing the code. Even if you provide user details with full access to the folder in the code, if the user executing the code doesn't have access, it will fail. Instead, you can restrict users not to modify the files by having some checks in the code.